# AjaxControlToolkit 3.5 - ReorderList scrolling div issue

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ajaxcontroltoolkit, asp.net-3.5, vs-web-site-project

I have a ReorderList inside a vertically "scrollable" DIV tag which does not work when the scrollbar for DIV tag is already scrolled and we try to re-order visible items.

For details, please refer http://forums.asp.net/p/1068063/1550532.aspx.
I changed the script and now want to build framework 3.5 assembly.

I was able to download AjaxControlToolkit source code from codeplex and re-build the toolkit, under framework 4.0

How should I proceed to build it so that it is compatible with 3.5 web site project.

Please note that this all should be possible from Visual Studio 2010 and NOT 2008.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No responses ?
I had to open ajax control toolkit 2008 solution and create a new assembly from there.

But there should be some way ?